# JavaScript to get rows count of a HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

How to get with JavaScript the rows count of a HTML `table` having id and name?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Given a

```html
<table id="tableId">
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td>Footer</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

and a

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
```

there are two ways to count the rows:

```
var totalRowCount = table.rows.length; // 5
var tbodyRowCount = table.tBodies[0].rows.length; // 3
```

The `table.rows.length` returns the amount of ALL `<tr>` elements within the table. So for the above table it will return `5` while most people would really expect `3`. The `table.tBodies` returns an array of all `<tbody>` elements of which we grab only the first one (our table has only one). When we count the rows on it, then we get the expected value of `3`.

Comment: This would include child tables' rows in the count as well though: http://jsfiddle.net/GYstV/

Comment: I suppose the OP didn't specify, though I do think it was implied it was the total parent table's rows. However, this solution would be helpful in counting all the rows in the parent table and its child tables; therefore, I believe it would be best if that were made clear in the explanation of the solution. I would edit to convey that, but I do not have enough rep for it to go through yet...

Comment: this answer worked to me, because I needed desconsider the thead/tfoot and get only rows with data.

Comment: `table.tBodies[0].rows` is the key

Answer (score 105):

You can use the [`.rows` property](http://wwwht.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_rows.asp) and check its [`.length`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp), like this:

```
var rowCount = document.getElementById('myTableID').rows.length;
```

Comment: and what if there is class in table instead of id?

Comment: @SagarKodte Get first value from getElementsByClassName. const rowCount = document.getElementsByClassName('table-xxx')[0].rows.length;

Answer (score 15):

```
$('tableName').find('tr').length
```

Comment: Or better still `$('#tableId tr').length`, or even better `$('#tableId tbody tr').length`.

Comment: Thanks @SharpC, $('#tableId tbody tr').length worked like charm in google chrome dev console as well.

Answer (score 4):

If the table has an `ID`:

```
const tableObject = document.getElementById(tableId);
const rowCount = tableObject[1].childElementCount;
```

If the table has a `Class`:

```
const tableObject = document.getElementsByClassName(tableClass);
const rowCount = tableObject[1].childElementCount;
```

If the table has a `Name`:

```
const tableObject = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
const rowCount = tableObject[1].childElementCount;
```

**Note:** index `1` represents `<tbody>` tag

Comment: What to do if table doesn't have tbody

Answer (score 0):

This is another option, using jQuery and getting only `tbody` rows (with the data) and desconsidering `thead/tfoot`.

> $("#tableId > tbody > tr").length

```js
console.log($("#myTableId > tbody > tr").length);
```

```css
.demo {
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
   border-collapse:collapse;
   border-spacing:2px;
   padding:5px;
}

.demo caption {
   caption-side:top;
   text-align:center;
}

.demo th {
   border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
   padding:5px;
   background:#F0F0F0;
}

.demo td {
   border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
   text-align:left;
   padding:5px;
   background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTableId" class="demo">
   <caption>Table 1</caption>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Header 1</th>
         <th>Header 2</th>
         <th>Header 3</th>
         <th>Header 4</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tfoot>
      <tr>
         <td colspan=4 style="background:#F0F0F0">&nbsp; </td>
      </tr>
   </tfoot>
</table>
```