# Display alert window when last row from table gets deleted

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table, dynamic-tables

I have a table in which I dynamically add and delete rows. This is the code I wrote to do that

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
var count = "2";
function addRow(in_tbl_name)
{
var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
// create row
var row = document.createElement("TR");
// create first col
var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml1 = "This is the line number " + count;
td1.innerHTML = strHtml1.replace(/!count!/g,count);
// create second col
var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
var strHtml2 = "<INPUT TYPE='Button' CLASS='Button' onClick='delRow()' VALUE='Delete Row'>";
td2.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g,count);

// append data to row
row.appendChild(td1);
row.appendChild(td2);
// add to count variable
count = parseInt(count) + 1;
// append row to table
tbody.appendChild(row);
}

function delRow()
{
var current = window.event.srcElement;
//here we will delete the line
while ( (current = current.parentElement)  && current.tagName !="TR");
     current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
}
</SCRIPT>
```

And here is the code for the HTML elements.

```
<div id="container">
<INPUT TYPE="Button" onClick="addRow('tblPets')" VALUE="Add Row">

<TABLE ID="tblPets" border="1" STYLE="border width:1 orange dashed;background color:#F0E68C;table-row width:2;">

    <TR><TD>Frist col</TD><TD>Second col</TD></TR>
    <TR><TD>This is the line number 1.</TD><TD><INPUT TYPE="Button" CLASS="Button" onClick="delRow()" VALUE="Delete Row"></TD></TR>

</TABLE>
</div>
```

So far everything is working fine. the last step that I can't think of how to complete is, when I delete every row from the table, an alert message will appear saying `alert("Table is empty");`.

How can I do that? how can I make my `delRow()` function to understand when the table gets completely empty?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: if (current.parentElement.rows.length==o) ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript to get rows count of a HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053503/javascript-to-get-rows-count-of-a-html-table)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if(document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length == 1)
  alert("this is last row ")
else if (document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length == 0)
  alert("table is empty now ")
```

Answer (score 0):

actually that was a silly question of me.. i just did it using my count variable..

with this simple if

```
if ( count == 1 )
    alert("Table is empty");
```