# how can i hide whole table when row count is 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a project about e-commercial website. I have problem with Cart section. I want to show one table if there is some goods on cart but if there is no i wanna show another table.

Here is my HTML code for tables

```html
<div class="sepet">
  <div id="dialog" title="Ürün Açıklaması">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <table id="sepettablo" align="center" class="roundedCorners">
    <tr>
      <th>Ürün</th>
      <th>Açıklama</th>
      <th>Adet</th>
      <th>Birim Fiyatı</th>
      <th>Fiyat</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\5.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\6.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\3.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="images\4.jpg" style="height:100px;" alt="Alternate Text" /></td>
      <td id="aciklama"><span class="opener" style="cursor:pointer;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span></td>
      <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
          onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
      <td>
        <span class="shop-price" style="cursor:default">129.99 TL</span>
      </td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="toplam">
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>
        <td><i style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="arttir()" class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i> <input type="button" id="sonuc" value="1" /> <i onclick="azalt()" style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-circle-minus"></i> <i style="cursor:pointer;" class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"
            onclick="urunsilme()"></i></td>
        <td>Toplam:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table class="sepetbos" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span>Sepetiniz boş. Ürün eklemek ister misiniz?</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS codes if it's needed.

```css
table.roundedCorners {
  border: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  text-align: center;
}

table.roundedCorners tr td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border-top: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border-right: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border-left: 1px solid DarkOrange;
}

#aciklama {
  max-width: 50px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table.roundedCorners td,
table.roundedCorners th {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

table.roundedCorners tr:last-child>td {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

table.sepetbos {
  border: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border: 1px solid DarkOrange;
  border-radius: 13px;
  border-spacing: 1px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 1440px;
  text-align: center;
  /*display:none;*/
}

table.sepetbos tr:last-child>td {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 13px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 13px;
  text-align: center;
}

table.sepetbos span {
  cursor: default;
}

table.sepetbos td,
table.sepetbos th {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

there it is. I have a function about deleting rows but it's just deleting rows. I want to disappear all table and show another table (class=sepetbos).

function about deleting rows

```js
function urunsilme() {
  var td = event.target.parentNode;
  var tr = td.parentNode;
  tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: Where's the code for that "function" for deletion? Why not check for the rowcount within that function, and act accordingly?

Comment: i added javascript code

Comment: Putting all your original code only complicates your question. You should ask your question here with just meaningful code. [There are explanatory pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on stackoverflow on how the site works; you should read them all ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), along with all the subpages. They help to maintain the spirit of mutual aid here

Comment: just look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053503/javascript-to-get-rows-count-of-a-html-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the row count in the table, whenever you remove the row. And as soon as it is zero hide the table.

```
function urunsilme() {
     var td = event.target.parentNode;
     var tr = td.parentNode;
     tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
     var rowCount = document.querySelectorAll('#sepettablo tr');
     if(rowCount.length == 0) {
       document.querySelector('#sepettablo').style.display = "none";
       document.querySelector('.sepetbos').style.display = "table";
      }
}
```

Comment: i am not asking for this. i ask for when row count hits 0 by using my function urunsilme() table "sepetbos" shows.

Comment: Ok modified the answer accordingly.